# Server-side method does not write to database unless client-side caller is paused/interrupted (via alert)

Tags: ajax, async-await, sqlclient

I am using an Ajax `post` method to pass a JSON string to a server-side `MVC` action.  The `IActionResult` method parses the JSON string into an `array` which is uploaded into SQL Server via `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` methods.  The `IActionResult` returns an `Ok()` result to the caller upon completion.

The anomaly I have observed is that the database upload (server-side) only completes if I pause/interrupt the browser by placing an `alert` just after the Ajax method (client-side).  My code is as follows:

Client-side:

```
function ExportJSON() {
    var myJson = "some JSON stuff goes here";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Dailies/UploadJson/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { jsonString: myJson },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
    alert("Your data has been saved.");
}
```

Server-side action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadJson(string jsonString)
{
    if (jsonString != null) {
        var myJArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);
        TimePunches[] timePunches = myJArray.ToObject<TimePunches[]>();

        try 
        {
            string constr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MYSQLSERVER");
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                foreach (TimePunches timePunch in timePunches) {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO TimePunches([Projectid], [CrewLeaderId]) ";
                    query += "VALUES(@Projectid, @CrewLeaderId) ";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query)) {
                        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projectid", timePunch.Projectid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrewLeaderId", timePunch.CrewLeaderId);
                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            TempData["msg"] = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

To reiterate, the server-side action uploads data to the database (as expected) so long as the `alert` is present in the client-side `ExportJSON()` method.  Conversely, removing the `alert` causes the database upload to fail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this issue.  The following link provides an excellent article explaining the nuances of asynchronous `JavaScript` calls and, in particular, how to manage synchronization issues when using `Ajax`: https://stackify.com/return-ajax-response-asynchronous-javascript-call/

In my particular case the solution was as simple as adding an `async: false` qualifier to my `Ajax` "post" method.